# Extract an interface/type from a typed function

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

If I have a typed function that I am importing called `foo` ie.

```
const foo(opts: {name:string, vers?:number, init:(...args)=>void }) => []
```

Is there a way to extract the type of `opts` from this function into it's own type/interface?

ie

```
interface IFooOpts = <TYPE OF foo(OPTS)>
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and the [inference behavior of conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) to extract the type of the first argument in a type alias:

```
declare function foo(opts: {name:string, vers?:number, init:(...args)=>void }) : []

type IFooOpts = typeof foo extends (opts: infer U) => any ? U : never;
```

Comment: This works! thanks, Got a link to some docs so I can make sense of this?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 added links to relevant keywords

Comment: is it possible to extract all the argument this way ie. `typeof foo extends (...opts: infer ...U) => any ? U : never;`

Comment: @lonewarrior556 Yes you can in 3.0. Have a look here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897 Basically „typeof foo extends (...opts: infer U) => any ? U : never;„